# Запись в лист в два и более потока

Tags: java

Добрый день. Интересует простой пример на Java как организовать мультипоточную запись/чтение из коллекции.
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего, вероятно, воспользоваться синхронизированными коллекциями:

```
List<C> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<C>());
```

Запись и чтение получатся автоматически синхронизированными, вы можете свободно работать из разных потоков. Это, однако, касается лишь добавления/удаления: обращение по индексу или итерирование требует синхронизации:

```
list.add(new C());

synchronized (list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
        // работаем с i.next()
}
```

[[Документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)]